# How to import a file in Flask uWSGI Nginx?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I checked every SO question about it, but the answers are mainly on import errors while I do not have such a problem. Mainly I followed [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) followed by [this one](https://github.com/mjhea0/flask-basic-registration) to have a functioning registration.

Instead of using Flask-SQLalchemy I wanted to create my own database (for fun), but when I try to access the database (`DButils.py`) functions it occurs an internal server error.

The flask code at the top is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, session, 
from wtforms import Form, StringField, TextAreaField, PasswordField, validators
from functools import wraps
from DButils import *
```

My folder follows the same order of the git, with `DButils.py` in the same folder as `app.py`.

I did not encounter the error when I import the module, but only when I try to call its functions. In `DButils.py` I have only a signup function:

```
def signup(nick, email, password):
    return True
```

And when I try to call it in the `app.py` code like:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def register():
    form = RegisterForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        email = form.email.data
        nick = form.nick.data
        password = form.password.data
        signup(nick,email,password) #WHEN COMMENTED NO ERROR OCCURS
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

I get the message "*Internal Server Error*" with no other clue about it. What can it be? How can I call a function in an external module in Flask?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you checked Nginx logs? Provide any relevant info from them into this question.

Comment: Why are you running via nginx when you're still in development, rather than using the built in dev server? And you should start your app with debug on so you can see what the actual error is.

Comment: Because I am already finished developing in my localhost, where I do not have this issue. I am now trying to migrate into production, but I got this issue that did not present itself in local.  The nginx log say    '*678 connect() to unix:/home/sammy/myproject/myproject.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by an trial-error approach. Apparently using `pkill --signal SIGHUP uwsgi` in combination with `sudo systemctl restart nginx`.